# How to insert json array data into mysql?

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

Hi I'm trying to insert the json array into my MySQL database.With array json data from android client.

```
{"message":[ {"body":"Fdsa","_id":"114","status":"-1","address":"null","read":"1","type":"3","date":"1429781969573","thread_id":"2"},{"body":"wtf2","_id":"113","status":"0","address":"0123456789","read":"1","type":"1","date":"1429590050090","thread_id":"1"}, {"body":"wtf2","_id":"112","status":"0","address":"0123456789","read":"1","type":"1","date":"1429590050090","thread_id":"1"}]}
```

how to parse json data into database ?

```
$message_data = json_decode($data,true);

printf($message_data['message']);die;
```

Comment: Where is the MySQL codes ?

Comment: once you've decoded the JSON string with that `true` flag, it'll be just your ordinary array. just treat it as you normally would and use PDO or MySQLi API to make your insertions

Comment: but not parse to string "message"

Comment: `$message_data = json_decode($data,true);` is an array, so you can just then do `$message_data['message'];` to get everything else

Comment: Keep in mind that you are passing null as text - it will not work as expected (address).

Answer (score 0):

your data:

```
{
    "message": [
        {
            "body": "Fdsa",
            "_id": "114",
            "status": "-1",
            "address": "null",
            "read": "1",
            "type": "3",
            "date": "1429781969573",
            "thread_id": "2"
        },
        {
            "body": "wtf2",
            "_id": "113",
            "status": "0",
            "address": "0123456789",
            "read": "1",
            "type": "1",
            "date": "1429590050090",
            "thread_id": "1"
        },
        {
            "body": "wtf2",
            "_id": "112",
            "status": "0",
            "address": "0123456789",
            "read": "1",
            "type": "1",
            "date": "1429590050090",
            "thread_id": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

when you `json_decode($data)`

it will be an **object** like this

```
stdClass Object
(
    [message] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [body] => Fdsa
                    [_id] => 114
                    [status] => -1
                    [address] => null
                    [read] => 1
                    [type] => 3
                    [date] => 1429781969573
                    [thread_id] => 2
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [body] => wtf2
                    [_id] => 113
                    [status] => 0
                    [address] => 0123456789
                    [read] => 1
                    [type] => 1
                    [date] => 1429590050090
                    [thread_id] => 1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [body] => wtf2
                    [_id] => 112
                    [status] => 0
                    [address] => 0123456789
                    [read] => 1
                    [type] => 1
                    [date] => 1429590050090
                    [thread_id] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

---

but if you do this `json_decode($data, true)`

```
Array
(
    [message] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [body] => Fdsa
                    [_id] => 114
                    [status] => -1
                    [address] => null
                    [read] => 1
                    [type] => 3
                    [date] => 1429781969573
                    [thread_id] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [body] => wtf2
                    [_id] => 113
                    [status] => 0
                    [address] => 0123456789
                    [read] => 1
                    [type] => 1
                    [date] => 1429590050090
                    [thread_id] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [body] => wtf2
                    [_id] => 112
                    [status] => 0
                    [address] => 0123456789
                    [read] => 1
                    [type] => 1
                    [date] => 1429590050090
                    [thread_id] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

---

after that you can insert it to db with foreach your `$message_data->message` or `$message_data['message']`